# IPFS Hash Storage In RAM Cost/Hash Question

Tags: ram, hash, ipfs

According to [**this**](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17094/how-to-store-ipfs-hash-using-bytes/17112#17112), an IPFS hash can be represented with **32 bytes**.

1. Would these hashes need to be stored in **RAM**?
2. If so, is it limited to 1 file stored per hash?
3. Would it be ~$0.20/hash to store in RAM if we assume:

   - ([.0228 eos for 32 bytes * $8.87/eos](https://www.eosrp.io/#calc)) = ~$0.20?

---

[image]

---

[image]

Slide from Dan's presentation on ["Scaling Blockchain Computation and Storage"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2cXC7YUm7Rk)

Comment: For 1., that depends on your use case. What is this. You could also browse the history to find a transaction with your hash. See http://eosproof.io/ for example.

Comment: For 2., you could also store the hash of a directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, if your contract needs to access hashes. In other word, if you store hashes in multi-index table rows, it needs RAM.
2. From the view of IPFS, a hash represents a file. Whatever the content it has.
3. Your math is correct. But the RAM price you gave is 0.0228/32*1000 = 0.7125 EOS/KB, pretty much on the recent spike. The RAM has gone crazy lately and thus gives you the answer $0.20/hash. Now the market calms down a little. By the time I'm answering this question, the price is 0.47 EOS/KB. https://eos.feexplorer.io/